OS selection menu is not displayed (black screen) but active
After fresh install of dual boot of Windows 10 with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on 9 years old LENOVO laptop, the OS selection screen is not visible at start up - I just see a black screen - but the menu is active, as by moving up and down with the arrows keys, respectively Windows or Ubuntu can be selected.
Browsing various posts, I tried out already various settings of GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT but without success. Below the latest intent.
Could anyone please help me solving this?
Below I show details of /etc/default/grub, HW components and grub.cfg
Kind regards
jan
Below the uncommented lines of /etc/default/grub
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.modeset=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

Below the HW characteristics
CPU:
  Info: dual core model: Intel Core i7-5500U bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    smt: enabled arch: Broadwell rev: 4 cache: L1: 128 KiB L2: 512 KiB L3: 4 MiB
  
Speed (MHz): avg: 1048 high: 2397 min/max: 500/3000 cores: 1: 2397 2: 798
    3: 500 4: 500 bogomips: 19155
  
Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3

Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 5500 vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 v: kernel
    arch: Gen-8 ports: active: HDMI-A-1,eDP-1 empty: none bus-ID: 00:02.0
    chip-ID: 8086:1616 class-ID: 0300

  Device-2: Syntek Lenovo EasyCamera driver: uvcvideo type: USB rev: 2.0
    speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 2-4:3 chip-ID: 174f:14e6 class-ID: 0e02
    serial: <filter>

  Display: wayland server: X.org v: 1.21.1.11 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: X: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa
    dri: iris gpu: i915 display-ID: 0

  Monitor-1: HDMI-A-1 model: Philips 244E serial: <filter> res: 1920x1080
    dpi: 92 size: 531x299mm (20.91x11.77") diag: 609mm (24") modes:
    max: 1920x1080 min: 720x400

  Monitor-2: eDP-1 model: ChiMei InnoLux 0x1490 res: 1366x768 dpi: 112
    size: 309x173mm (12.17x6.81") diag: 354mm (13.9") modes: 1366x768

  API: EGL v: 1.5 hw: drv: intel iris platforms: device: 0 drv: iris
    device: 1 drv: swrast surfaceless: drv: iris wayland: drv: iris x11:
    drv: iris inactive: gbm

  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: intel mesa v: 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.2
    glx-v: 1.4 direct-render: yes renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 5500 (BDW
    GT2) device-ID: 8086:1616 display-ID: :0.0

Below the Grub.cfg file
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${initrdfail}" = 2 ]; then
   set initrdfail=
elif [ "${initrdfail}" = 1 ]; then
   set next_entry="${prev_entry}"
   set prev_entry=
   save_env prev_entry
   if [ "${next_entry}" ]; then
      set initrdfail=2
   fi
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function initrdfail {
    if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -n "${partuuid}" ]; then
      if [ -z "${initrdfail}" ]; then
        set initrdfail=1
        if [ -n "${boot_once}" ]; then
          set prev_entry="${default}"
          save_env prev_entry
        fi
      fi
      save_env initrdfail
    fi; fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt5'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5  08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=es_ES
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=0
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 0 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
set gfxpayload="${1}"
if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
else
set vt_handoff=
fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if [ ${grub_platform} != pc ]; then
      set linux_gfx_mode=keep
    elif hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5' {
recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt5'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
 search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5  08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5
else
 search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5
fi
linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-49-generic root=UUID=08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5 ro  quiet splash i915.modeset=1 $vt_handoff
initrd /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-49-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5' {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 6.8.0-49-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.8.0-49-generic-advanced-08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5' {
recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt5'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
 search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5  08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5
else
 search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5
fi
echo 'Loading Linux 6.8.0-49-generic ...'
linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-49-generic root=UUID=08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5 ro  quiet splash i915.modeset=1 $vt_handoff
echo 'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
initrd /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-49-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 6.8.0-49-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.8.0-49-generic-recovery-08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5' {
recordfail
load_video
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt5'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
 search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5  08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5
else
 search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5
fi
echo 'Loading Linux 6.8.0-49-generic ...'
linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-49-generic root=UUID=08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr
echo 'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
initrd /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-49-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 6.8.0-48-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.8.0-48-generic-advanced-08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5' {
recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt5'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
 search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5  08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5
else
 search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5
fi
echo 'Loading Linux 6.8.0-48-generic ...'
linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-48-generic root=UUID=08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5 ro  quiet splash i915.modeset=1 $vt_handoff
echo 'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
initrd /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-48-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 6.8.0-48-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.8.0-48-generic-recovery-08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5' {
recordfail
load_video
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt5'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
 search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5  08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5
else
 search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5
fi
echo 'Loading Linux 6.8.0-48-generic ...'
linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-48-generic root=UUID=08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr
echo 'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
initrd /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-48-generic
}
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+x64.efi)" --class memtest $menuentry_id_option 'memtest86+' {
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt5'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
 search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5  08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5
else
 search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5
fi
        linux    /boot/memtest86+x64.efi
}
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+x64.efi, serial console)' --class memtest $menuentry_id_option 'memtest86+-serial' {
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt5'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
 search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5  08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5
else
 search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 08d2dae6-1362-4061-b76b-2703197238c5
fi
        linux   /boot/memtest86+x64.efi console=ttyS0,115200
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/25_bli ###
if [ "$grub_platform" = "efi" ]; then
  insmod bli
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/25_bli ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-0695-10CF' {
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
set root='hd0,gpt1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
 search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  0695-10CF
else
 search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0695-10CF
fi
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
if [ "$grub_platform" = "efi" ]; then
fwsetup --is-supported
if [ "$?" = 0 ]; then
menuentry 'UEFI Firmware Settings' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
fwsetup
}
fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/35_fwupd ###
### END /etc/grub.d/35_fwupd ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###

